# shared pointers and multithreading

Tags: c++, multithreading, shared-ptr, tbb

I have been using the following code for quite some testing now and havent run into any problems, however I just realized that the code might be not threadsafe and lead to raceconditions.

```
...
std::shared_ptr<T> ptr(new T(bar));

auto foo = [=] (tbb::blocked_range<int> r) {
     std::shared_ptr<T> p(ptr); // <- Is this threadsafe?
     // ... do stuff
};

tbb::parallel_for(tbb::blocked_range<int>(0,x), foo);
...
```

My question is concerning the marked line, as I think during the copy construction of the shared pointer racecondititons might occur due to increasing the referencecount.

Though I could just avoid that by captureing the pointer by reference and using it directly but I am still interested in the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, if you compile with the options for multithreading turned on, the library should be using atomic operations or locks for the reference count of shared pointers. There are no thread safety issues with the code as you've posted it.

Comment: well, I am not setting any special options for multithreading, just linking to tbb, I am compiling as followed: g++ -std=c++0x -Wall -Werror -Wextra -pedantic-errors -o main main.cpp -ltbb

Comment: @bamboon: Well, in my experience, unless you give the `-pthread` option to gcc, it won't link multithreaded programs properly, and in some cases will give errors when compiling them.

Comment: strange, could it be that there were some changes with some version of gcc or that tbb is managing that somehow by its self?

Comment: @bamboon: What is tbb? Do you have a link? The last version of gcc I experienced this with was 4.6. :-)

Comment: @bamboon: It's a shared library. And it depends on symbols in the thread library, but your program doesn't directly depend on those symbols. So linking works. Hmm...  Looking at the assembly output, it looks like, even without `-pthread` the compiler is still producing thread safe code for the reference counts.

Comment: ok, thanks for the research. But you recommend always adding the -pthread option for safe multithreading?

Comment: @bamboon: No, reading the documentation it merely sets things up in the preprocessor and linker to use the Posix threads library directly. It apparently does not affect the thread safety of the code. Though, since it sets preprocessor options, I would not necessarily trust that to be true and compile with it anyway.